# Repository cannot be found on set_github_release + github actions

Tags: github-actions, fastlane

I am building the CI/CD of a new app, and everything works fine locally, but when I put in Github Actions the `set_github_release` simply doesnt work with the following error: `Repository matheusjkweber/SafetyGuard cannot be found, please double check its name and that you provided a valid API token (GITHUB_API_TOKEN)`. Everything else works fine.

The github token is provided by Github Actions, and this is the lane:

```rb
lane :create_release_candidate do |options|
    remove_last_branch_of_type "release"

    # Prepare to build branch
    tag = "v#{version}"

    UI.success tag

    release_branch = "release/#{tag}"

    puts "target release branch: #{release_branch}"

    sh "cd ..; git checkout -b #{release_branch}"
    sh "cd ..; git push -u origin #{release_branch}"

    remove_tag tag

    add_git_tag(
      tag: tag
    )

    push_git_tags(
      tag: tag
    )

    github_release = set_github_release(
      repository_name: REPOSITORY_NAME,
      api_token: ENV['GITHUB_TOKEN'],
      name: "#{tag}",
      tag_name: "#{tag}",
      description: (File.read("changelog") rescue "No changelog provided"),
      commitish: release_branch
    )
end
```

Comment: Relevant issue: https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/issues/16618. Looks like you can use `api_bearer` instead of `api_token` or set `FL_GITHUB_RELEASE_API_BEARER` environment variable. See its last two comments and the linked PR.